# How to check status of things when device disconnect not gracefully on aws iot core

Tags: aws-iot, arduino-esp8266

I am using AWS IoT core for communication between Esp8266 with the application. But I could not read the state of the device when it disconnected not gracefully . Any help is helpful. Sorry my English is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Connect/Disconnect Events
AWS IoT publishes a message to the following MQTT topics when a client connects or disconnects:
Go to the AWS iot core and subcribe both topic and pass your clientID

$aws/events/presence/connected/: A client connected to the message broker.

$aws/events/presence/disconnected/: A client disconnected from the message broker.

other wise you can subcribe to this topic also

[$aws/events/presence/connected/#](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html)

[$aws/events/presence/disconnected/#](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html)

you get the status for disconnected and vice versa for connected

For details you can have a refrence https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html

Comment: what is the exact topicname?? AWS Documentation barely holds any examples in the documentation- 

is it:

`$aws/events/presence/disconnected/<client_id>`
or `aws/events/presence/disconnected/<client_id>`

or is it just `$aws/events/presence/disconnected/#` or `$aws/events/presence/disconnected/` or no '$' prefix??

Comment: you can use any random name for the topic example : 'test topic'

Comment: no, I wanted those very topics, anyways I figured out that it is `$aws/events/presence/connected/#` and `$aws/events/presence/disconnected/#` and likewise for subscribe and unsubscribe!

Comment: so its the same answer you have figured out what I have given

Comment: hey! I was asking for exact topicname, clearly mentioning how AWS Doc has been obfuscating here, my question was different and a random name like `test-topic` wasnt what I 'm looking for. 
And even per your answer, with both `../connected` and `../connected/#` mentioned, it was me trying for a combination of such suffixes from none to `<clientid>` to finally `#` that worked. but anyways thanks buddy, I somehow reached there chancing upon '#' and some other advisory had such suffixed topics for a different use altogether!